Playwright (TS) - API tests error on a '401', but only within one spec file
So I have a set of 12 spec files with various tests. All of them are working as expected, par one file that returns a 401 error on all requests doe within it. All of my tests get the api key from the "playwright.config.ts" file and I have had no issues calling the same endpoints across others test spec files.
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
const jobData = require("./test-data/jobData.json");
const atpData = require("./test-data/atpData.json");

const companyId = "b6408970-7d37-4e36-0e42-08dbb38a3296";
const resourceId = "0d421901-1dca-4855-f8fa-08dca56c8760";
const assessmentCompleteId = "b98fedb0-6d7f-4570-2e5a-08dca4bc7c1d";

let currentDateTime: any;
let updatedDateTime: any;
    test("Create job", async ({ request }) => {
        const response = await request.post(`companies/${companyId}/jobs`, {
            data: JSON.stringify(jobData),
        });
        expect(response.status()).toBe(201);
        expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
        jobId = await response.json();
    });

The above post request is the same request done in my other tests
I've tried setting the HTTPHeaders within the spec file itself with the same issue, and creating a new file has the same issue again

We don't have your backend or JSON data so this doesn't appear reproducible. Please share all code necessary to run and repro the issue, a [mcve]. Thanks.
